# Moving the mouse without acceleration in C++ using mouse_event

Tags: c++, winapi

Right now when I try a loop that contains  something like:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,dx,dy,0,0);
```

The mouse tends to move more than (dx,dy). Researching this online, I think it's because of the acceleration applied by the operating system. How can I move the mouse an absolute amount?

MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE seems to maybe be what I'm looking for, but I can't see how to use it.

I've tried:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE || MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,dx,dy,0,0);
```

but that doesn't work either. I'd prefer to use mouse_event rather than SetCursorPos or other methods, what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to put 2 pipes in (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE || MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE) or is that a typo?

Comment: I did have it as || before, but I realize that it's wrong. I switched it to |, but now it just ends up moving the cursor to (0,0) now matter what dx or dy are

Answer (score 5):

The coordinates are not pixel coordinates and must be normalized.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int WINAPI _tWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {
  INPUT input = {0};

  int screenX = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN );
  int screenY = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN );

  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    input.mi.dx = i*10 * ( 65535/screenX );
    input.mi.dy = i*10 * ( 65535/screenY );
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;

    SendInput( 1, &input, sizeof INPUT );
    Sleep( 1000 );
  }

  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have used SendInput() here instead of mouse_event() because the latter has been superseded according to the docs. If you do want to convert it back, the parameters should be much the same.

Answer (score 4):

from winuser.h

```
#define MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE        0x0001
#define MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE    0x8000
```

`MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE || MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` is the same thing as `0x0001 || 0x8001` which evaluates to `true`, which just happens to be 1!

Try it again with `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` and it will probably work.

Edit:
after looking at the docs a bit, it appears that either you want `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` all by itself. or you need to account for the fact that the range of values it is looking for is 0-65535 scaled over the entire display.

> If MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE value is specified, dx and dy contain normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface, (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner.

Comment: Okay, when I switch it to |, it just immediately moves the cursor to the (0,0) spot, even when I try mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,100,100,0,0) for example

Comment: added a hopefully relevant quote from the MS docs to my answer